# Inline if statement inside datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable, inline-code

I am not sure whether the question is asked before. but i couldnt find it. Thats the reason i am asking now.

I have to use more datatables. so i am writing a common function to call it again and again by passing parameters. For that common code, i have to use inline if statement to add column widths, here i attached my code. someone help me to insert the inline condition inside it.

```
function common_datatable(file_ajax, module_name, btns_list, widths, view_btn) {            
  return $('#'+module_name+'_table').DataTable({ 
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": file_ajax, 
    "bLengthChange": false, "bAutoWidth": false , "sScrollX": "100%", 
    aoColumns : [
        (widths[0] !=0) ? '{ "sWidth": "1%" }' : '',            
        { "sWidth": "30%" },
        { "sWidth": "30%"},
        { "sWidth": "9%"}           

    ],  orderCellsTop: true,
    "scrollX": true,
    "order": [   [1, "asc"]  ], 
    "columns": [{"orderable": false}, null, null,  null, null, null ]
  });       
}
```

The above code i passed array of width's through the width parameter, this is the code i am using,

```
(width[0] !=0) ? '{ "sWidth": "1%" }' : '',
```

but its not working inside it.

Comment: What does _its not working inside it._ mean?

Comment: inline if statement is not working. its showing an error " Unexpected ("

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to initialize an array with conditional element as you are trying. Try like following

```
    function common_datatable(file_ajax, module_name, btns_list, widths, view_btn) {            
        var aoColumns = [                
            { "sWidth": "30%" },
            { "sWidth": "30%"},
            { "sWidth": "9%"}
       ];
        if(widths[0] != 0) {
            aoColumns.unshift({"sWidth": "1%"});
        }

        return $('#'+module_name+'_table').DataTable({ 
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": file_ajax, 
            "bLengthChange": false, "bAutoWidth": false , "sScrollX": "100%", 
            "aoColumns": aoColumns,  
            "orderCellsTop": true,
            "scrollX": true,
            "order": [   [1, "asc"]  ], 
            "columns": [{"orderable": false}, null, null,  null, null, null ]
        });       
    }
```

Comment: Well what's the result?

Comment: Thank you for the help, yes its working . i dont have reputations to vote you. sorry.

Comment: You Are Awesome Man . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The variable name in function is widths and you are using width in if statement

> Try using this: (widths[0] !=0) ? '{ "sWidth": "1%" }' : '',
>  
>   instead of: (width[0] !=0) ? '{ "sWidth": "1%" }' : '',